# how to determine Java thread behavior

Tags: java, multithreading

I am doing a Java past exam paper and I feel confused about the following question:

Q: Which one statement is always true about the following application?

```
class HiPri extends Thread {
    HiPri() {
        setPriority(10);
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println(“Another thread starting up.”);
        while (true) { }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        HiPri hp1 = new HiPri();
        HiPri hp2 = new HiPri();
        HiPri hp3 = new HiPri();
        hp1.start();
        hp2.start();
        hp3.start();
    }
}
```

A. When the application is run, thread hp1 will execute; threads hp2 and hp3 will never get
the CPU.

B. When the application is run, thread hp1 will execute to completion, thread hp2 will execute to completion, then thread hp3 will execute to completion.

C. When the application is run, all three threads (hp1, hp2, and hp3) will execute concurrently,taking time-sliced turns in the CPU.

D. None of the above scenarios can be guaranteed to happen in all cases.

I select D, as I think both B and C are possible but not guaranteed to happen. The key answer is C however. Did I missing something here? Could anyone please clarify that for me? Many thanks.

Comment: There is no completion with an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, the key is in the wording of answers A and B

> ... hp2 and hp3 will *never* get the CPU.

It would seem that *if you agree* that all threads will start, then this is an invalid answer because all have received at least some CPU.

> ... will execute to completion ...

the `while (true) {}` will loop forever, which clearly makes this false.

By process of elimination, only answer 'C' makes sense.

***Edit:*** *As noted in some of the other comments, answer A will depend on if one assumes preemptive multithreading.*

Answer (score 1):

B is not possible because the amount of work each thread has to do is infinite.

To be truly pedantic, however, the program is not legal Java because it contains [unreachable statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21). So one can argue that it can do anything.

Comment: @user2864740 I do not believe a Java implementation is required to implement pre-emption, so A is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Check [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29). All 3 methods return instantly and start a new `Thread`, which executes infinitely because of the `while(true)` loop in the body of the `run()` method.

> public void start()
>
> Causes this thread to begin execution; the Java Virtual Machine calls the run method of this thread.
>
> The result is that two threads are running concurrently: the current thread (which returns from the call to the start method) and the other thread (which executes its run method).
>
> It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution.

Comment: So what is your answer?

Comment: @EJP I didn't think it was rocket science to connect "all 3 methods start a thread which runs infinitely" with answer C...

Comment: I have no idea of the OP's capabilities, nor of those of every future reader of this answer. Neither do you. Best to answer the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the options your best answer here should be:

> C. When the application is run, all three threads (hp1, hp2, and hp3)
>   will execute concurrently, taking time-sliced turns in the CPU.

But thread scheduling varies on different platforms and depends on implementation of JVM.

A nice article to read on [Thread Scheduling](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-07-2002/jw-0703-java101.html?)

Cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. D is correct and C is wrong. The JLS says:

> "Threads may be supported by having many hardware processors, by time-slicing a single hardware processor, or by time-slicing many hardware processors."

So time-slicing is not mandatory, and neither is a single ("the") CPU. So no answer that relies on both can possibly be correct.